# Number_format for arabic/persian numbers

Tags: php, mysql, regex, formatting

I have a "price" field in a mysql database, which contains the price of a product in arabic or persian numbers.

**Example of number: ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰** *//1234567890*

I cannot figure out how to format this so that it is formatted in a user-friendly way.
By that I mean, grouped by thousands or something similiar.
This would be ideal: **۱ ۲۳۴ ۵۶۷ ۸۹۰**

number_format in php is what I would have used on latin numbers.

Is there any function which I don't know about, to make this possible?

If not, ideas of how to create one is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you store prices in your database layer using appropriate numeric data types; and convert to the desired arabic/persion/whatever format in the presentation layer, upon displaying to the user.

Comment: so in other words, there is no function which does this easily otherwise. Also, the problem is that users input the numbers in arabic/persian upon posting a product. OK thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like this:

```
([۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰])(?=(?:[۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰]{3})+$)
```

Search and replace with `\1,` on the string `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰` would give you `۱,۲۳۴,۵۶۷,۸۹۰` (using `,` instead of space since SO trims them off. But using space in the replace instead will work just as well).

I would have to agree with the suggestion in the comments though, store the data using the numeric types available and convert them on input/output.

Answer (score 0):

If you can store numbers in your database instead of strings (or convert to ascii numbers), then standard currency formatting with group-separators can be done with php5-intl functions. You  just need ISO locale and currency codes:

```
$nf = new \NumberFormatter('fa_IR', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $nf->formatCurrency(1234.1234, 'IRR');
```

۱٬۲۳۴ ﷼

Otherwise, @rvalvik's answer is good.

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Answer (score 0):

More elegantly written than @rvalvik's regex pattern, you can add a comma after a character that is followed by 3, 6, 9, etc. characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7IEq8))

```
$str = '۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰';

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~.\K(?=(?:.{3})+$)~u',
        ",",
        $str
    )
);
```

Output:

```
'۱,۲۳۴,۵۶۷,۸۹۰'
```

Here is [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179221/2943403) to a related question.