# Add a space between every 2 characters starting from the end of a string

Tags: php, string, delimiter, spacing

I want to add space before every two characters from the end of the string.

```
$str = 9010201;
```

The result should be `9 01 02 01`.

I tried `chunk_split()` and `str_split()`, but it worked only from the beginning of the string but not from the last.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simple use `strrev()` and `chunk_split()`

```
<?php

$str = 9010201;

echo trim(strrev(chunk_split(strrev($str),2, ' ')));

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

You need to use [`strrev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) and [`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) function.

```
<?php
$str = 9010201;
$rev = strrev($str);
$split = trim(chunk_split($rev, 2, ' '));
echo strrev($split); //9 01 02 01
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `strrev` will reverse the string to `1020109`, then use chunk_split() and reverse it again.

```
<?php
    $str = 9010201;
    echo strrev(trim(chunk_split(strrev($str),2,' ')));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex allows this to be done in a single function call without any trimming.

Simply add a space at every position that is followed by an even number of characters.

Don't worry, you won't encounter an infinite loop -- the string is evaluated entirely before applying replacements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aiB6G))

```
$str = 9010201;

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~.\K(?=(?:.{2})+$)~',
        " ",
        $str
    )
);
```

Output:

```
'9 01 02 01'
```

Pattern breakdown:

```
.          #match any character
\K         #do not consume previously matched character
(?=        #lookahead (consume no characters)
  (?:      #encapsulate expression logic without capturing
    .{2}   #match any two characters
  )+       #require one or more of the expression
  $        #match the end of the string
)          #end of lookahead
```

The effect of the pattern on the provided string adds a space just before the sixth-from-the-end, fourth-from-the-end, and second-from-the-end characters.

If the pattern was `(?=.{2}+$)`, the regex engine would interpret the `+` incorrectly.  The `+` would explicitly demand that the `{2}` quantifier must use "greedy"/possessive matching (not give back characters when possible) -- but that is not helpful or intended in this case. [Demo of wrong behavior.](https://3v4l.org/amZOP)