# Split 5 or 6 character number before fourth-last number

Tags: php, string, date, split, text-parsing

I get POST request date strings in the format of `mY` (no leading zeros on the month), so there's no delimiting character to split on.

Examples: `122019` or `62019`

I need to separate the five or six digit string into a one or two digit month and a four digit year.

Eg1 :  122019

```
$a[0] = 12;
$a[1] = 2019
```

Eg2 : 62021

```
$a[0] = 6;
$a[1] = 2021
```

Comment: Somewhat related regex solution logic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45476087/2943403

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about this date format, especially about how you use an integer as a date. But let's consider that it's on purpose, the year is always gonna be 4 character, so you can just get the year by taking the last 4 char and use the rest as the month.

Using **substr()** see [PHP.NET Substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

> Return part of a string

And you can specify the start and length of the part you want to get, or using - to get character starting from the end of the string.

```
$weirdDate = 122019;

//takes the last 4 character
$year = substr($weirdDate , -4);
//takes the string from the beginning to 4 char before the end
$month = substr($weirdDate , 0,strlen($weirdDate)-4);

echo $year;
echo $month;
```

Again, it seems like a weird way to get a month/year date, but i'm answering based on the assumption that a year is gonna be 4 char long.

If it's not, you can't really split the number since the month part can be 1 or 2 char long.

```
09-2019 would be 92019 
11-2019 would be 112019
```

Comment: Why the year should be 4 characters ?

Comment: Well, this is a weird date format that seem to use an integer for the date. So I guess 09-2019 is gonna be 92019, but if you don't force the rule that a year is 4 char long, there is no way to do such a thing as arbitrarly splitting the date with this format since there is no way of knowing if the month is one or two char long.

Answer (score 3):

A simple use of the `substr()` function will do this nicely

```
$in = '122019';

$year = substr($in,-4);
$month = substr($in,0, strlen($in)-4);

echo $year . ' month ' . $month;
$a[] = $month;
$a[] = $year;
```

RESULT

```
2019 month 12
array (
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 2019
)
```

Or if we use `$in = '62019';`

The RESULT would be

```
2019 month 6
array (
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 2019
)
```

> Reference ['substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 2):

- You could also use `substr` with `strpos`. With `substr()`, you could first get the year by providing a negative offset to start capturing from back of the string as the year is going to be 4 digits. Then, you could use `strpos()` to find the index of the year and use this as the ending index to get the month.
- That being said, best way to deal with this data is to either have a proper date format or better to have a JSON string with proper keys for days, month and year along with date.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$str = '122019';

$year = substr($str,-4);
$month = substr($str,0,strpos($str,$year));

echo $month," ",$year;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have one another solution to use `str_replace()` with `substr()` like:

```
<?php
$string = "122019";
$year = substr($string, -4);
$date = str_replace($year, "", $string);
$myArray = array($date,$year); // convert into an array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
?>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 2019
)
```

**Side Note:** This will only work, if your year based on last 4 characters and other then these 4 characters must be date, as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this feat with two function calls, use negative parameters with `substr()` calls.

There is no reason to call `strlen()`, `strpos()`, or `str_replace()`.

For a single call technique, use `preg_split()` with a lookahead pattern to ensure that no characters are consumed while exploding.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RBYn5))

```
$mY = '62021';
var_export([
    substr($mY, 0, -4), // month
    substr($mY, -4)     // year
]);

echo "\n---\n";

var_export(
    preg_split('/(?=\d{4}$)/', $mY)
);
```