# Add commas as thousands delimiter in Arabic money number expression

Tags: php, csv, arabic, multibyte, money-format

i am looking for a regular expression to insert commas into a numbers. For example, I have `999999999` and I want to insert a thousand separator.

I know I can use `number_format()`, but that doesn't solve my problem since my digits are actually in Arabic format `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰`.

Maybe there is a regular expression to insert a character after certain number of characters in a string.

I tried using `preg_replace()`, but couldn't find the answer.

I found the below code from one of the answers on stackoverflow but it throws error:

```
$num = '۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰';
$n = preg_replace(/([۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰])/,(?=(?:[۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰]{3})+$),$num);
echo $n;
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16524286/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @JellyBean answer

```
$num = '۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰';
$newNum = wordwrap($num , 6 , ',' , true );
```

This will echo out `۱۲۳,۴۵۶,۷۸۹,۰`

First of, why 6?  Because The chars uses 2 bytes.
Second, there's still a problem; What we want is this: `۱,۲۳۴,۵۶۷,۸۹۰`

### Solution

We can reverse it

```
$num = strrev('۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰');
$newNum = strrev(wordwrap($num , 6 , ',' , true ));

echo $newNum;
```

`۱,۲۳۴,۵۶۷,۸۹۰`

POC: https://3v4l.org/OVeQQ

Answer (score 0):

Try using wordwrap

```
$num = '۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰';
$newNum = wordwrap($num , 4 , ',' , true );
```

this should output: '۱۲۳۴,۵۶۷۸۹۰'

source: [PHP.net wordwrap](https://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Comment: This answer does not provide the expected result because it is not multibyte-safe. https://3v4l.org/u3PkL

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$num = '۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰';
$ar = str_split($num, 3);
$result = implode(',', $ar);
echo $result;
```

Comment: `str_split()` corrupts multibyte characters. https://3v4l.org/kcrKf and https://3v4l.org/Up7g1 Please test your code before posting an answer.  Also, please always add educational explanations to your answers.  "Try this" answers are the least generous form of answer.